# add html tag in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this is probably simple but I can't find any information that fits this situation.
I have simple text like...

> Rinse the color from the hair, condition, rinse again, then gently towel dry… " + `"<b>"` + "Do not shampoo." + `"</b>"` + ". Dry hair about 75% and then apply final color over filled hair."

In this example the text I have wrapped in  is bold, but in my app, html and jquery, it doesn't.
How can I add html tags to a string of text?  I also need to wrap text in a p tag.

The text is being added dynamically to a div. It comes back to my function as

```
 var result = "text and then <b> text to be bold </b> more text.
```

I then add it to a div using jQuery.

Comment: Show us how you add the text to the DIV

Comment: Can you please show us an input that string of text or the result is that string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the JQuery `.html` method. If we wanted to alter the HTML content of some `div` with id ```enterTextHere``, we would make the following call:

```
$("#enterTextHere").html("text and then <b> text to be bold </b> more text.");
```

See this jsfiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/dx9yozj9/

Answer (score 2):

make sure you use the `.html` method like

```
$(target).html(str);
```

Comment: how do I add the tags so that they don't show as text but act like html tags.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for this. Just type: `element.innerHTML = result;`

Answer (score -1):

I hope this you are looking for

```
<div class="test"></div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var str = '';
    str = 'Rinse the color from the hair, condition, rinse again, then gently towel dry';

    str+='<b>Do not shampoo.</b>. Dry hair about 75% and then apply final color over filled hair.';
   $('.wrapper').html(str);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried this but the b tags show as text, the statement between them isn't bold.

Comment: Sorry! i corrected my mistake now